# Editar array dentro de outro array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Sou novo no AngularJS e tenho a seguinte situação:

Tenho uma lista de **categorias** e, dentro desta lista de **categorias**, há uma **listagem dos produtos** dessa categoria.

Exemplo: Smartphones > Galaxy, iPhone, etc...

O problema é que eu não consigo salvar a edição que eu faço desse array dos produtos que estão dentro do array de categorias.

Criei um [Codepen](https://codepen.io/brdppl/pen/KQNRKz?editors=1010) para ilustrar melhor esta situação.

Compreendo que o `$scope.save` está salvando a tabela, e não o conteúdo, porém não tenho uma ideia de como salvar o conteúdo ao invés da tabela.

Gostaria muito da ajuda de vocês, obrigado desde já.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu [crie um fork do seu codepen](https://codepen.io/OnoSendai/pen/RQoJbP?editors=1010) com uma solução possível.

Basicamente - guarde uma referência ao objeto original:

```
$scope.edit = function(user, i) {
    $scope.source = user; // Preservando a referência
    $scope.update = angular.copy(user);
};
```

E utilize [`angular.merge()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.merge) para sobrescrever as propriedades do objeto original com as do clone modificado:

```
$scope.save = function() {
    angular.merge($scope.source, $scope.update); // Atualiza o objeto referenciado
    $scope.update = ""; // reseta o update
};
```

Comment: Wow! Funcionou perfeitamente! Valeu pela orientação, vou dar uma lida neste angular.merge para entender melhor sua função. Muito obrigado!!

Comment: Fico feliz que tenha funcionado, @BernardoSampaio!